# I want to make alias for git checkout and git pull with detecting a branch parameter for zsh or bash

Tags: git, zsh, oh-my-zsh

So I have problem with 2 command with parameter in middle of argument. I want to checkout and pull branch by this function in my .zshrc:

```
gleap() {
   git checkout "$1"
   git pull
}
```

And is working.
But the problem is, I can't detecting what the branch I want. when I press **tab** in my terminal, it somehow autofilling with directory from same level as my terminal location, for example:

```
gleap node_modules/
```

Is there any trick for solve this problem?

Comment: Say `man zcompsys`.

Answer (score 0):

In `bash` with installed [bash-completion](https://repology.org/project/bash-completion/versions) I do the following:

```bash
. /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/git
gleap_comp() { __gitcomp_nl "$(__git_refs)" ; }
complete -F gleap_comp gleap
```

Read completion helper functions, declare a function `gleap_comp` that completes only references (branches and tags), install the function as the completion helper for command `gleap`.

See [Programmable Completion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Line-Editing.html). See my [`.bashrc`](https://phdru.name/Software/dotfiles/) for many other examples.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [git-completion](https://github.com/felipec/git-completion/wiki/Zsh), just do:

```
compdef _git gleap=git_checkout
```

It's explained [here](https://github.com/felipec/git-completion/wiki/Zsh).